# Symfony2 & MSSQL Server persisting dates

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, symfony

I have an Entity with a column "fecha" (datetime) mapped to an SQL Server database.
When I try to persist to the database, an error raise:

> An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE tor_jornada SET fecha =
>   ?, cancha = ? WHERE id = ?' with params ["2014-09-14 00:00:00.000000",
>   1, 286]:
>
> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>   Server]Conversion failed when converting datetime from character
>   string.

When I put the query in the SQL Server Management, it raise an error.
Then I cut the right zeros in the milliseconds, change "2014-09-14 00:00:00.000000" to "2014-09-14 00:00:00.00" and it works fine!

So, can I change this in Symfony? How? Where?

The entity:

```
namespace IM\ManTorneosBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TorJornada
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tor_jornada", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_AB7D06987CEB63FE", columns={"torneo"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TorJornada
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="jornada", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $jornada;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fecha", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $fecha;

 .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Format your datetime before with this :

```
  $date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Then insert the $date as parameter in your query, this should give you "2014-09-14 00:00:00"

Comment: Where? I save object to database with: *** $em->persist($jornada); $em->flush(); *** Doctrine make the sql automatically.

Comment: `code`
namespace IM\ManTorneosBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class jornadaType extends AbstractType
{
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
  $builder
   ->add('fecha', 'datetime')
   ->add('cancha', 'integer')
   ->add('equipo1')
   ->add('equipo2')
   ->add('marcador1')
   ->add('marcador2')
   ->add('Guardar', 'submit');
 }
 
 public function getName()
 {
  return 'jornada_form';
 }
}
`code`

Comment: I don't know how insert indentation in comments, sorry.

Comment: try this in place of fecha `$builder->add('fecha', null , array(
                
                'date_widget' => "single_text",
                'time_widget' => "single_text",
                'required'  => true
            ))` if you still have a weird date format format it inside your controller, `$fecha = $entity->getFecha(); $fecha = $fecha->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); $entity->setFecha($fecha);`

Comment: This last suggestion wouldnt work cause with it you're changing your data from Datetime to string and feeding it to Symfony object. Symfony will choke on it when it tries to actually use the value it gets and convert it to a string on its own. It does a ->format() on given datetime object. I would like though, to hear a nice solution for this. I know you can solve it with using datetime2 type in MsSql instead of datetime...